# What does the 7-day peak usage limit for quotas mean on Google Cloud?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube data API for a course project. The Quotas easily get up to 10000 while testing and the Google Cloud Platform website gives little support or explanation.

Exceeding 10 000 quotas in the "current usage" quote disables retrieving data, but the 7-day peak usage seems to keep things running, but without any info on what that actually means.

I wouldn't want to fail my project because of exceeded quotas.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/quota_and_compliance_audits) where you may need to check [YouTube API Terms of Service](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) and YouTube's Developer Policies. After that submit the [Audited Developer Requests Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_audited_developer_requests_form)

Comment: Thanks @Pedro, I have seen them and understand that I need to fill them out to receive more quotas. I was just wondering what the 7 day peak means, as it isn't stated anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "7 Day Peak Usage" is not a limit. It's an indicator about the peak usage in the past 7 days. It helps you see limits that are at risk of being exceeded.

For the given scenario, there is a need to request 25% quota increase.

The "Current Usage" of 1300 means, it is the usage so far in the current day, as YouTube Data API is a daily quota.

Please see below for further reference:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_all_quota_console